PFE Sheet how to prevent resize with frozen columns in PF7
I have been working with primefaces, and the sheet component meet most of the requirements that I need to accomplish my work, did some research and added contextual menu and other functions, but my main problem is visual, if I put some columns fixed, and I move to the right all the rows are resized automatically, I have decided to avoid the fixed columns but anyway if I move the cursor a few columns to the right the row's height is resized.
This is my code:  (many words in spanish because it is my first language)
Some of the custom things i added
 <ui:define name="head">

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var $settings = {
                contextMenu: {
                    callback: function (key, options) {
                        if (key === 'borrar') {
                            eliminar();
                        } else if (key === 'editar') {
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                verDetalleProducto();
                            }, 100);
                        }
                    },
                    items: {
                        "borrar": {name: 'Eliminar linea'},
                        "editar": {name: 'Ver Detalles Adicionales'}
                    }
                }
            };

            function sheetExtender() {
                // this = widget
                // this.cfg = JSON configuration
                this.cfg.trimWhitespace = true;


                $(document).ready(function () {


                    var $hot = PF('sheetWidget1').ht;
                    console.log($hot);
                    $hot.updateSettings($settings);
                });

            }
            ;

            function sheetExtender2() {
                // this = widget
                // this.cfg = JSON configuration
                this.cfg.trimWhitespace = true;


                $(document).ready(function () {

                    var $hot2 = PF('sheetWidget2').ht;
                    console.log($hot2);
                    $hot2.updateSettings($settings);

                });

            }
            ;
        </script>

    </ui:define>   

This is my table:
<pe:sheet id="sheet1" 
          widgetVar="sheetWidget1" 
          value="#{sheetController.productosExcel}" 
          var="row"    
          
          rowKey="#{row}"
          showRowHeaders="true"
          resizableCols="true"                                                   
          resizableRows="false"
          readOnly="false"                                                 
          height="#{(sheetController.productosExcel.size() le 5) ?  (75 + sheetController.productosExcel.size() *50) : 75 + 5 * 50}"
          rowStyleClass="#{ row.cantidad gt 0 and row.precioUnitario gt 0 ? 'correcto' : 'incorrecto'  }"                                              
          extender="sheetExtender"                              
          >

    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText style="color: white;" value="Productos Agregados"/>
    </f:facet>

    <p:ajax event="change" update="tabs:sheet1 :form:growl" listener="#{sheetController.cellChangeEvent}"/>
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":form:growl" listener="#{sheetController.rowSelectEvent}"/>
    <p:ajax event="cellSelect" update=":form:growl" listener="#{sheetController.rowSelectEvent}"/>

    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Código Insumo"
                    readOnly="true"          
                    colType="numeric"
                    value="#{row.idProducto}"                                                           
                    colWidth="100"
                    numericPattern="00000000"
                    >
    </pe:sheetcolumn>



    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Renglón"                                                
                    readOnly="true"          
                    colType="numeric"                                                
                    value="#{row.idRenglon}"                                                                                                                                                                 
                    colWidth="80">
    </pe:sheetcolumn>

    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Insumo"                                                
                    readOnly="true"          
                    colType="text"                                                
                    value="#{row.nombre}"                                                                                                                                                                
                    colWidth="80">
    </pe:sheetcolumn>

    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Presentacion"                                                
                    readOnly="true"          
                    colType="text"                                                
                    value="#{row.presentacion}"                                                                                                                                                                
                    colWidth="120">
    </pe:sheetcolumn>                                        


    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Comentario"
                    readOnly="false"
                    colType="text"
                    value="#{row.comentario}"                                              
                    colWidth="250"/>                                       

    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Cantidad Enero"
                    readOnly="false"                                                               
                    colType="numeric"
                    value="#{row.enero}"    
                    colWidth="150"/>

    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Cantidad Febrero"
                    readOnly="false"          
                    colType="numeric"
                    value="#{row.febrero}"    
                    colWidth="150"/>

    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Cantidad Marzo"
                    readOnly="false"          
                    colType="numeric"
                    value="#{row.marzo}"    
                    colWidth="150"/>


    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Cantidad Abril"
                    readOnly="false"          
                    colType="numeric"
                    value="#{row.abril}"    
                    colWidth="150"/>


    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Cantidad Mayo"
                    readOnly="false"          
                    colType="numeric"
                    value="#{row.mayo}"    
                    colWidth="150"/>


    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Cantidad Junio"
                    readOnly="false"          
                    colType="numeric"
                    value="#{row.junio}"    
                    colWidth="150"/>


    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Cantidad Julio"
                    readOnly="false"          
                    colType="numeric"
                    value="#{row.julio}"    
                    colWidth="150"/>

    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Cantidad Agosto"
                    readOnly="false"          
                    colType="numeric"
                    value="#{row.agosto}"    
                    colWidth="150"/>




    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Cantidad Septiembre"
                    readOnly="false"          
                    colType="numeric"
                    value="#{row.septiembre}"    
                    colWidth="150"/>

    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Cantidad Octubre"
                    readOnly="false"          
                    colType="numeric"
                    value="#{row.octubre}"    
                    colWidth="150"/>


    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Cantidad Noviembre"
                    readOnly="false"          
                    colType="numeric"
                    value="#{row.noviembre}"    
                    colWidth="150"/>

    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Cantidad Diciembre"
                    readOnly="false"          
                    colType="numeric"
                    value="#{row.diciembre}"    
                    colWidth="150"/>

    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Cantidad Anual"
                    readOnly="true"
                    colType="numeric"
                    numericPattern="0.00"
                    value="#{row.cantidad}"                                              
                    colWidth="150"/>


    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Costo Unitario"
                    readOnly="false"
                    colType="numeric"
                    numericPattern="0,0.00"
                    value="#{row.precioUnitario}"                                              
                    colWidth="150"/>

    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Total"
                    readOnly="true"
                    colType="numeric"
                    numericLocale="es-GT"
                    numericPattern="0,0.00"
                    value="#{row.precioUnitario * row.cantidad}"                                              
                    colWidth="150"/>

</pe:sheet>

normal size
after a few columns to the right:
other size
Faces version: 2.1.17
EDIT: Primefaces 6.2 as pnd primefaces extension 6.2.11
It is very similar to the next question but it has no responses
Primefaces Sheet How to Remove Row Resize Functionality
I tried with some css stuff but it did not work, sorry for bother you users, greetings.
EDIT: Primefaces 6.2 as pnd primefaces extension 6.2.11

You didn't mention your version of PFE?  That users in the other was using PFE 6.2 which is quite old.  What version are you using?

@Melloware Sorry for the delay, you are right! My version is 6.2 as well, and primefaces extension: 6.2.11, I added it to the main question as well.

I feel like this is fixed already in a later PFE.

@Melloware thank you for the informartion gonna analyze if it is worth to upgrade the PFE version to avoid the issue

Report back if it does or doesn't fix it.

@Melloware hello, i tried to upgrade at least to  PFE 7.0 since the changelog is not that bad but the bug persists unfortunately, doing a major upgrade ( to PFE 8 or beyond)  requires a bigger effort due to the big changes (and this is an old app with some functionalities already developed).
A lot of components really changed, so probably gonna stick with the current version and try to work around it without impact too much the user experience, if somebody else knows a method to at least patch the issue i would be really thankful, really appreciate your  help Melloware.

I would like to post a partial solution for this issue, after a break and analyzing the js code from the sheet primeface extension found the property that can help, in my case just needed to overwrite the 'rowHeights' key into the setting variable.
The key 'rowHeights' is called by the hook 'modifyRowHeight' defined in the js file for this extension, so doing this we can avoid the 'resize' if we can find a value that fits the most of our values, maintaining the same height for all the rows.
var $settings = {
            rowHeights: 80, //<--- this is the value to overwrite
            contextMenu: {
                callback: function (key, options) {
                    if (key === 'borrar') {
                        eliminar();
                    } else if (key === 'editar') {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            verDetalleProducto();
                        }, 100);
                    }
                },
                items: {
                    "borrar": {name: 'Eliminar linea'},
                    "editar": {name: 'Ver Detalles Adicionales'}
                }
            }
        };

function sheetExtender() { //Defining the sheetExtender function

           
            this.cfg.trimWhitespace = true;                
            
            $(document).ready(function () {                    
                var $hot = PF('sheetWidget1').ht;
                $hot.updateSettings($settings);
            });
            
        }

Thanks for your help.
